# upgrade php to 5.2 on centos 5

Tags: linux, php, centos

I'M triyng to upgrade php 5.1 to 5.2 on centos 5 [following these directions](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2).

I enabled the centos-testing repo:

But yum can't find any package to upgrade...

```
rpm -qa |grep php
php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-common-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-xml-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-xmlrpc-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-pear-1.4.9-8.el5
php-cli-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-pdo-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-soap-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-gd-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-mysql-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-5.1.6-39.el5_8
php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1
php-devel-5.1.6-39.el5_8
```

---

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: mirror.nexcess.net
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

---

```
yum update php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: mirror.nexcess.net
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

---

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Testing.repo 
#CentOS-Testing:
#!!!! CAUTION !!!!
#This repository is a proving grounds for packages on their way to CentOSPlus and CentOS Extras.
#They may or may not replace core CentOS packages, and are not guaranteed to function properly.
#These packages build and install, but are waiting for feedback from testers as to
#functionality and stability. Packages in this repository will come and go during the
#development period, so it should not be left enabled or used on production systems without due
#consideration.
[c5-testing]
name=CentOS-5 Testing
baseurl=http://dev.centos.org/centos/$releasever/testing/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dev.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-testing
includepkgs=php*
```

Any help please?

Comment: 5.2 is far out of date, and so are the directions you linked to. You should be looking at 5.3 or 5.4 for a current system, and perhaps be using CentOS 6.

Comment: Please, use proper markup to format your post (http://serverfault.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the remi repositories.
Instructions on installing the remi repos can be found here
http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

I would opt to go down the yum route (rather than trying to install rpms)
You will however have to import the remi GPG key.

Once installed, you can install php using the following command:

```
yum --enablerepro=remi install php
```

Its probably a good idea to do a yum search first to check the correct name for the version you need.

Also, this post may be of assistance: [Upgrading PHP from 5.1 to 5.2 on CentOS 5.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/283054/upgrading-php-from-5-1-to-5-2-on-centos-5-4?rq=1)